# Xen on ARM Cortex A9

Tags: xen, arm, para-virtualization

I see that there is a version of the [Xen hypervisor for ARM CPUs](http://www.xenproject.org/developers/teams/arm-hypervisor.html).

However, most ARM CPUs appear not to have virtualisation extensions (and are not otherwise efficiently virtualisable). Hence I looked into Xen with paravirtualisation for ARM.

But [that project seems to be on hold since 2012](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/XenARM).

Is there any way to run Xen (presumably the paravirtualisation version) on a Cortex A9?

Comment: Hi, Did you finally find out if Xen can run on Cortex A9 processor?

Comment: No. Never could find a Cortex A9-based device to buy...

Comment: Then did you run Xen on any ARM board?